# В чем разница при использовании даты в формате "Y-m-dTH:i:s" и "Y-m-d H:i:s"

Tags: php, дата

Пытался найти мануалы по php, но в подкорку не проникло:

```
Дата в формате стандарта ISO 8601 (добавлено в PHP 5)
2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

согласно стандарту [*iso 8601*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

> [T] is used as time designator to indicate:
>
> - the start of the representation of local time to designate local time expressions as such,
> - the start of the representation of the time of day in date and time of day expressions,
> - the start of the representation of the number of hours, minutes or seconds in expressions of duration;

мой вольный перевод:

> [T] используется в качестве разделителя, указывающего:
>
> - начало представления локального времени для отделения локального времени как такового,
> - начало представления времени дня в выражении, содержащем дату и время дня,
> - начало представления количества часов, минут или секунд в выражениях продолжительности.

---

дальше в тексте стандарта уточняется, что этот разделитель обязательно должен применяться в указанных целях в случае возможной неоднозначности интерпретации выражения.

но есть и оговорка:

> NOTE
>   By mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange, the character [T] may be omitted in
>   applications where there is no risk of confusing a date and time of day representation with others defined in this
>   International Standard.

мой вольный перевод:

> примечание: по совместному соглашения между партнёрами, осуществляющими обмен информации, символ `[T]` может быть опущен в приложениях, где нет риска спутать представления даты и времени дня с другими представлениями, описанными в этом международном стандарте.

---

**резюме**

**отсутствие** `T` допустимо (согласно стандарту и в оговоренных случаях), но **замена** `T` на пробел **не соответствует** стандарту *iso 8601*.

Answer (score -1):

T добавляет смещение в зависимости от часового пояса в настройках php.

Comment: Т.е. учитывает часовую зону сервера и делает смещение?

Comment: Не зону сервера, а зону из настроек PHP. Они могут не совпадать.

Comment: этот ответ неверен.

Comment: временная зона учитывается в обоих вариантах, просто в первом она показывается в выводе, а во втором нет.

`
    <?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Adak');
 echo date('c');
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Minsk');
 echo date('c');
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    ?>
`

и результат

`
    2015-10-02T00:11:07-09:00
    2015-10-02 00:11:07
    2015-10-02T12:11:07+03:00
    2015-10-02 12:11:07
`

-09 и +03 соответствуют установленному часовому поясу

дебильный тут редактор текста, код не оформляется как код